# allignment on grid column (wpf)

Tags: wpf, grid

I have a grid which its columns are centred aligned. For example every image that is on a cell in this grid, is centred on its cell. There is nothing in grid definition that sets this .
The grid definition is as follow:

```
 <Grid Canvas.Left="16" Canvas.Top="229" Visibility="{Binding Status,
                                     Converter={StaticResource EnumToVisibilityConverter},
                                     ConverterParameter='OK,Processing'}"  IsEnabled="{Binding Status,
                                     Converter={StaticResource EnumToBoolConverter},
                                     ConverterParameter='OK'}" >

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"  />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"  />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="image1.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="111" Height="20" />

        <Image  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Source="image2.png" Width="49"  Height="17"/>

    </Grid>
```

Both of the above images are centred aligned.

I checked parent canvas and there is nothing there to dictate that it should be centred.
Is there a way that I set the alignment of a grid column to left?

Is there any tools that I can see where the property of each component is set? (Similar to what developer toolbar do for CCS and HTML)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set the `HorizontalAlignment` of the `Image` to the Left if you need, as I'm pretty sure `Center` is the default alignment.

```
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" ......
```